# I don't understand how the Telekinesis spell works

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I don't understand a bit about some things in the [spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/telekinesis), like:

1. After moving a creature once with the spell, is it possible to move it another 30 feet on your next turn?
2. If you change the target of the spell, is another spell slot spent or not?

Comment: I revised the terminology to be consistent with the English edition of the rules, does that seem to capture your question correctly?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and maybe visit the [help] for having some guidance for posting questions and answers, if you need any. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

##### *After moving a creature once with the spell, is it possible to move it another 30 feet on your next turn?*

Yes, this is directly provided by the spell description (emphases mine):

> You gain the ability to move or manipulate creatures or objects by thought. When you cast the spell, and **as your action each round for the duration**, you can exert your will on one creature or object that you can see within range, causing the appropriate effect below. **You can affect the same target round after round**, or choose a new one at any time. If you switch targets, the prior target is no longer affected by the spell.

The above text indeed allows to *exert your will* by using your action on one creature or object, and you can affect the same target round after round. When you affect a creature the spell's text tells whatyou can do:

> **Creature.** You can try to move a Huge or smaller creature. Make an ability check with your spellcasting ability contested by the creature's Strength check. If you win the contest, you move the creature up to 30 feet in any direction, including upward but not beyond the range of this spell. Until the end of your next turn, the creature is restrained in your telekinetic grip. A creature lifted upward is suspended in mid-air.
>
> On subsequent rounds, you can use your action to attempt to maintain your telekinetic grip on the creature by repeating the contest.

The last line says that you can do the same action again by repeating the contest.

##### *If you change the target of the spell, is another spell slot spent or not?*

No, the text explicitly says

> You can affect the same target round after round, or **choose a new one at any time**.

This means that you can change the target at any time, *during the duration of the spell*: if the spell required another slot to be cast, or if it had different effects with a further casting, it would have say so. For example, for checking spells that explicitly say what happen with multiple casting, see the [Thaumaturgy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thaumaturgy) cantrip: one cast of it allows to create one effect, but multiple castings allow to have up to 3 contemporary effects:

> If you cast this spell multiple times, you can have up to three of its 1-minute effects active at a time, and you can dismiss such an effect as an action.